# Wrong number returns from EEPROM.get arduino

Tags: arduino, eeprom

In the setup function i clear the EEPROM if a specific button is clicked.
in the loop function at the start i have this code:

```
if(millis() - last_sample >= 180){
      sampler();
     EEPROM.get(stateEEPROMAdress, stateCode);
      stateCode = getState(stateCode);
    EEPROM.put(stateEEPROMAdress, stateCode);
    Serial.println(stateCode);
}
```

and a bunch of sampling code.
then at the end of the loop i have:

```
if(millis() - last_xbee >= 900){
EEPROM.get(packetEEPROMAdress,packetCount );
    EEPROM.get(stateEEPROMAdress,stateCode);
if(!initializing || (stateCode!= 0 &&  stateCode != 1)){
telemetry[2] = packetCount++;}
telemetry[21] =stateCode;  
EEPROM.put(packetEEPROMAdress, packetCount);
```

.... and printing codes...

I also at the start of the sketch i have defined :

```
const int packetEEPROMAdress =  0;
const int stateEEPROMAdress = packetEEPROMAdress + sizeof(int);
```

and this is the getState function. simple state determination from sensor values:

```
int getState(const int stateCode=0){
  int outState;
  //state 0
if(stateCode == 0 &&(fabs(verticalSpeed) < 2 || fabs(relativeAltitude) < 5)&&initializing){
  outState = 0;

  //true should change later to see is launch botton is on
} else
if(missionReady && !initializing && stateCode == 0){
    outState = 1;
}else if(verticalSpeed > 3&&stateCode == 1){
    outState = 2;
} 
//else 
//if(VerticalSpeed < 3 && stateCode == 2){
//  stateCode = 2;
//  //apogee but no code in CDR
//} 
else if(verticalSpeed < 2 &&stateCode == 2){
      outState = 3;
} else if((fabs(relativeAltitude - 450)< 10 || relativeAltitude<440 ) &&stateCode == 3){
        outState = 4;
}else
//true should be replaced with seperation photocell is bright
if(true && stateCode == 4){
  outState = 5;
}else if(relativeAltitude < 3 && fabs(verticalSpeed) < .7 && stateCode == 5  ){
  outState == 6;
  //activate Buzzer stop telemetry
}


return outState;
}
```

everything a good when state is 0 . when i send a command and states becomes 1. the after a few loops that 1 appears. the number in EEPROM becomes 8663 . is there a problem in addressing the EEPROM?

Answer (score 0):

It was sth silly:)
Nothing related to EEPROM. 
I didn't give a initial value to outState so large number stored in EEPROM,
Sorry if i got your time:)